# Can I upgrade an ADSL router firmware to DD-WRT or Tomato?

Tags: router, dd-wrt, adsl, tomato

I have an ISP-supplied ADSL modem/router with firmware upgrade options listed in the admin options. The router is probably not from one of the more popular router vendors - I could not find the model listed in the compatible devices list of Tomato / DD-WRT.

Router details:

> **Model**: Teracom T2-B-Gawv1.4U10Y-BI
>   **Firmware Version**: 10.4.3.12.12 DSL
>   **Firmware Version**: E.25.41.64 A

Is there a possibility for getting a new firmware with QoS support for this (my objective is to prioritise browsing and make it faster for P2P downloads) - or am I heading in the completely wrong direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the device is not listed with any of the open-source router firmwares, then chances are it won't work with them.

The device has to be based upon one of a small selection of chipsets, and the majority of the supported devices already run some form of embedded linux.

You would need an enhanced firmware from the router manufacturer, which I doubt exists.

Your best bet would be to go out and buy a router that is either on the DD-WRT, Open-WRT or Tomato lists, or one that already has the QoS in it that you desire.

Either that or just slow down your p2p downloads.  Most clients have options to do that.

Comment: but the p2p traffic is from 10+ machines which connect through wi-fi to the router. QoS options are there for this device too, but seem to control only 'upstream traffic'. Im not sure i can get the desired output, and i have been experimenting with options, without any results,

Comment: Agreed, also whenever I've looked in the past I've not actually found any ADSL routers that dd-wrt supports, as it doesn't have the adsl drivers in it, it's designed to work with cable routers

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/13sab.png here is a screenshot of the options. The dd-wrt/tomato users can configure the packets to ports 80,443 to prioritize browsing. im confused the above page will yeild the same results or not. one comment i got was this is applicable for Upstream traffic only and apparently cannot do speed limiting on p2p downlaods

Comment: You cannot control the speed that data arrives at your router - only the speed at which your router sends data out.  That's a limitation of QoS.  The closest you can do is to limit the speed at which outgoing requests for data happens.

Comment: Indeed.  There is no point in prioritising incoming data, as all that would mean is stopping stuff from coming in, so making your whole connection slower.

Answer (score 2):

Tomato and DD-WRT do not work on Router/Modems.
And QoS works upstream only - but that still affects your downstream the way you want it. 
You might buy a tomato/DD-WRT - router and connect that to your modem/router.

Comment: after buying a tomato/DD-WRT - router  also, the QoS will work in similer fashion as in adsl router?

Comment: The QoS options in a Tomato Router are probably much more developed than in your modem/router. But the principle is the same: the only way to reduce your mail is to write fewer letters :-) And with Tomato or DD-WRT you can get help from experts.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any tech specs on the modem so I can't say whether it'll run Tomato or DD-WRT, but I'd stick my neck out and say not.

You may find it simpler just to use a p2p app that supports bandwidth limiting - many do.

Also you may need to limit the number of peer connections the p2p software allows as too many can swamp a router's NAT table (if you are using NAT) and then everything grinds to a halt.

Comment: the firmware which teracom supplies have this model number internally-Solos
4610 RD / Solos 461x CSP v1.0  ; and this lead me to here http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.embedded.openwrt.devel/6586 ; something of interest

Comment: dead end.  DD-WRT incompatible devices list says [it wont work if it] has an integrated modem (dd-wrt is router firmware and does not support the modem part)